# How to delete photo from project's public folder before updating data in lumen/laravel?

Tags: laravel, lumen

I am trying to delete photo from my projects public folder before updating another photo. My code looks like-

```
if(File::exist( $employee->avatar)){
       //$employee->avatar looks /uploads/avatars/1646546082.jpg and it exist in folder

            File::delete($employee->avatar);
        }
```

This is not working in my case. If I comment these code then another photo updated without deleting perfectly. How can I solve the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try php unlink function 

$path = public_path()."/pictures/".$from_database->image_name;
unlink($path);
```

Comment: yes, I also try it. But it works if I don't check is the file exist or not? But I need to check is the file exist or not

Answer (score 1):

```
   This is the code which i use in update profile picture you can do this exactly like this               
      $data=Auth::user();
    if($request->hasFile('image')){
                    $image = $request->file('image');
                    $filename = 'merchant_'.time().'.'.$image->extension();
                    $location = 'asset/profile/' . $filename;
                    Image::make($image)->save($location);
                    $path = './asset/profile/';
                    File::delete($path.$data->image);
                    $in['image'] = $filename;
                    $data->fill($in)->save();
                }
```